# Expose WinCE setup kit to Active Sync

Tags: installation, windows-ce

I have a project that is a WinCe project so I created a cab file that I put on the device and then run it from there. However, I would like to know if it is possible to add my cab to the list of ActiveSync installabled programs so that I could install the cab from there. It's more user-friendly and since I'm not the one who will do it, I'de rather have it that way than formcing the user to do it from the gun.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for [The Application Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158696.aspx).

Basically, you have to:

1. [Write an .ini file describing your CAB file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158614.aspx)
2. [Run CEAppMgr.exe, passing it your .ini file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158592.aspx)